# Blackberry - message in notification bar without registering in native Messages app

Tags: blackberry, notifications, messaging

In RIM API documentation on class [ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig.setMessageListIntegration](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/messagelist/ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig.html#setMessageListIntegration%28boolean%29) it is said:

*defines whether folder messages should be integrated with unified message list*

Am I right thinking that it defines will folder be shown in native Messages application?

This question [on BB forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Message-in-notification-bar-without-registering-in-native/td-p/1462119)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `messageListIntegration` is set to true, a registered message folder and its contents will appear in the native Messages application.  When `homeScreenIntegration` is set to true, they will appear in the HomeScreen's notifications status screen.

Comment: Thank you for answer! My trouble is that if I set messageListIntegration = false, registered folder still appear in native Messages application (tested on simulator OS7 Torch 9850).

Comment: The doc you linked to is for OS6.  I don't see any changes mentioned in the OS7 doc, though.  Is `ApplicationFolderIntegrtionConfig.isMessageListIntegration()` returning True after you set it to False? Perhaps you are encounting a simulator/OS7 bug.

Comment: I just tried it in my OS6 Torch 9800 simulator and setting `messageListIntegration=false` works fine.

Comment: Turns out, if `messageListIntegration = true`, all registered messages will appear in main screen of native Messages app and registered folder will be accessible over Folders menu. If `messageListIntegration = false`, all registered messages **will not** appear in main screen of native Messages app **but still** registered folder will be accessible over Folders menu.  Anyway, accepting answer, thank you :)